# iPhone image button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to use image buttons in my iPhone application. Could you please let me know if there is any article I can read on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

So the suggestion from http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1891-changing-button-image-code.html is:

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal]
//No need to release img. It is autoreleased!!!
```

Comment: my image is round. When I load the image in the button, it shows rectangular button and the image on it. However, I just want to show the image, not the border of the button. Could you let me know how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to release img. So the correct code could be -

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: repeated answer. please remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically, you can do something like this...
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1891-changing-button-image-code.html

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder you can choose a Custom button and then set the Image property to your image. Don't use Rounded rect button, it will show behind the image.

Answer (score 0):

But you need to release the button ;)
[btn release];